# Having a component re-render on button press in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a simple React component that I'm working on creating right now. Basically, the user can input an ID and when they submit, it will display some information that is in a container. The code looks like so

```
export default class IDContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Id: '',
      isSubmitted: false
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      isSubmitted: true
    });
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      Id: event.target.value
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
              }}
          >
            <Input type={'text'} placeholder={"Enter Id"} value={this.state.Id} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Button type={'submit'} > Lookup </Button>
          </div>

          <div>
            {this.state.isSubmitted && <DetailsContainer Id={this.state.Id} />}
          </div>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The details container has already been created and just returns some details about the Id that has been passed in. I can show the details of the first Id that I pass in just fine. However, when I enter in another Id and submit the form, the DetailsContainer is not re-rendering and is still showing the details for the older Id. I tried moving it around and adding some logic (I even put the DetailsContainer in my state to see if I can manipulate it that way), but that doesn't seem to be working. I see that there is a `shouldComponentUpdate()` method, and that seems to be what I need to use, but the guides I saw all place it inside of the DetailsContainer. Anyway for me to have it in IDContainer, or is there an easier way to re-render the DetailsContainer?

Comment: You have this in your code: `<DetailsContainer Id={this.state.promotionId} />}` - is `this.state.promotionId` defined?

Comment: there appears to be some confusion between the `Id` and `promotionId` - are they supposed to be the same thing? Your Input updates a different one from that passed to the child (`DetailsContainer`) component...

Comment: Yes my bad, I have made the edits above. They should both be the same thing. Error in copying over the code.

Comment: Not an answer but you can replace the entire `constructor` function with this syntax: `state = { Id: '', isSubmitted: false }`

Comment: I think this has something to do with your isSubmitted state not changing after the first time it goes to true. So first time you submit, it turns to true and rerenders, but the second time, it is already at true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think part of the issue here is that once `isSubmitted` is set, every change you make to the input will be applied to `this.state.Id` and passed into `DetailsContainer`.

I think you'd be better off having one variable for tracking the input state, and variable one for tracking the Id you want to pass into `DetailsContainer`.

```
state = { Id: null, inputId: '' };

handleSubmit = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    Id: this.state.inputId
  });
};

handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({
    inputId: event.target.value
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <Input ... value={this.state.inputId} />
    ...
    {this.state.Id !== null ? <DetailsContainer Id={this.state.Id} /> : null}
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this and what's happening is that the DetailsContainer is now loading when the page is initially loaded with an empty Id. And, when I enter another id into my form it's still showing the DetailContainer for an empty Id. I want the DetailsContainer to render after the user clicks enter for the first time, and re-render every time they click submit again.

Comment: My apologies, there was a typo - the check for rendering `<DetailsContainer />` should be `this.state.Id !== null` (you only want to render the `DetailsContainer` once `Id` has been set, previously it was rendering as soon as `inputId` was set.

Comment: Ah, ok. So now the page is not showing the DetailsContainer on page load, and it is rendering after the user clicks search (Thank you!). However, DetailsContainer is not re-rendering after I click submit for a different Id (still showing details for the first Id).

Comment: This may be an issue with your implementation of `DetailsContainer`. Have you tried logging in the `render` function of `DetailsContainer` to see if the value is being passed in? You may need to add a `componentDidUpdate` handler to handle when the prop changes.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I have to change ```componentDidUpdate``` inside of DetailsContainer to make it update? Is there no way to do it inside of IDContainer? Asking because I'm not the one who wrote the DetailsContainer so I don't want to change it unless it's a must. Also, should I use ```componentDidUpdate``` or ```shouldComponentUpdate```? I intuitively think that I can have a comparison to see if the Id changed in ```shouldComponentUpdate``` and return True is so.

Comment: If you want to avoid modifying the `DetailsContainer`, you can force the `DetailsContainer` to unmount when you're changing the Id. For instance, try updating your `handleChange` method to set `Id` to `null` - `this.setState({ inputId: event.target.value, Id: null })`

Comment: This worked! So every time the Id becomes null, the DetailsContainer will unmount because of ```{this.state.Id !== null ? <DetailsContainer Id={this.state.Id} /> : null}```?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And it sounds like there's a `componentDidMount` function inside `DetailsContainer` that will read the prop being passed in.